# tag url template django doesn't work

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I trying to implement the url template tag into my project.
I have a button that allows the user to save the data he is seeing.
So the url of this button is this:

```
(2)url(r'^nameviews/download/$', 'my.path.is.this.to.download' name="load"),
```

template:

```
<a href="{% url load %}">Download</a>
```

the url of the page that shows the information, and where the button is located is:

```
(1)(r'^nameviews/$', path.to.page),
```

but when I tried to click on the button (it should appear the url 2)it doesn't open the file with the data but instead gives me the same url that the main page (1)

the html validator gives me a error on the

```
    <a href="">
```

It seems it doesn't recognize the url tag.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I didn't really understood what's happen because I didn't change much but should have been some silly mistake.

Sorry!
Thanks any way :)

**EDIT**

Be careful with the order of the urls. At urls.py try this order:

```
url(r'^nameviews/download/$', name_of_view, name="load"),
url(r'^nameviews/$', name_of_view, name="first page"),
```

**name_of_view** is equal if the view is the same

Comment: Can you post your solution ? Thanks.

Comment: my solution is already posted. there's something you didn't understand?

Comment: What did you do to fix this? I'm having the same problem.